# Loading display wont appear

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I'm writing a flash application with as3, this one if you want to look: http://www.kongregate.com/games/yossefki/nqueensolver

This application does some extreme calculation that take time. I want to display "loading" on the screen till the calculation is finished before the major calculation I write.

```
loadingText.visible = true
```

and after I write

```
loadingText.visible = false
```

but nothing is displayed. If I understand correctly the changes are made only when the calculation is finished and therefore its getting visible and back to invisible back again
and only then applying the changes.
Is there some way working around it?

Here is the function:

```
public function solve():void{
    //sizeOfBoard:int , solutionNumber:int):Array

    trace("start solving at queens");
    loadingText.visible = true;
    trace("loading set to visible");
    solutionNumDes++;
    solutionNumCounter = solutionNumDes;
    for(var i:int=0;i<_size;i++)
        solution[i] = 0;

    resetBoard();
    if(solveRec(0))
        display();
    trace("loading set to unvisible");
    loadingText.visible = false;
    trace("finised solving at queens");

}//solve
```

where `solveRec` is the heavy calculation

Comment: Could you maybe post the code of your class, so we can get an insight of what else is going on when you're setting the visibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your calculation takes longer than the frame refresh interval, the screen will freeze until the operation has finished.  You have to spread your calculation across more than frame, and then your setting the clip to visible and invisible will really show some results.

Check out [Pseudothreads](http://blogs.adobe.com/aharui/2008/01/threads_in_actionscript_3.html).  It's a neat and usable way to divide long calculations into sizeable parts and leave enough processing power for the Flash Player to redraw the screen in time.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be that you are doing the calculation and the visibility toggling in the same frame.

So basically what you probably are doing is this:

1. button clicked
2. `loadingText.visible = true;`
3. heavy calculations
4. `loadingText.visible = false;`
5. frame rendered

The problem here is that unlike asynchronous operations (like loading content), you have to 'wait' for the calculation to end. You could avoid this by waiting a frame until you start the calculations. To keep it simple, `loadingText.visible` could be a flag to indicate the need for calculation, that would be checked every frame.

1. button clicked
2. `loadingText.visible = true;`
3. frame rendered, loading text is visible now
4. on enter frame: check `if(loadingText.visible)`
5. heavy calculations
6. `loadingText.visible = false;`
7. frame rendered

You still can't do anything while calculating the result. That means showing a loading text works, but you can't have a fancy loading bar or spinning circle. To get that, you would need to use more advanced techniques to split the whole calculation over multiple frames by calculating only parts of it every frame.

You can split the functions like this:

```
private function solveButtonClicked():void {
    loadingText.visible = true;
}

private function enterFrame(e:Event):void {
    if(loadingText.visible) solve();
}

private function solve():void {

    solutionNumDes++;
    solutionNumCounter = solutionNumDes;
    for(var i:int=0;i<_size;i++)
        solution[i] = 0;

    resetBoard();
    if(solveRec(0))
        display();
    trace("loading set to unvisible");
    loadingText.visible = false;
    trace("finised solving at queens");

}//solve
```

Comment: i dont understand how can i do it...  this is the function i working in       public function solve():void{
   //sizeOfBoard:int , solutionNumber:int):Array
   
   trace("start solving at queens");
   loadingText.visible = true;
   trace("loading set to visible");
   solutionNumDes++;
   solutionNumCounter = solutionNumDes;
   for(var i:int=0;i<_size;i++)
    solution[i] = 0;
    
   resetBoard();
   if(solveRec(0))
    display();
   trace("loading set to unvisible");
   loadingText.visible = false;
   trace("finised solving at queens");

  }//solve

Comment: do u mean .. postponding the heavy calculation to the next frame?

Comment: @user1090419 yes. Because the display will be updated after the function `solve` finished. So yo need to wait at least for the next frame.

Comment: neat.. u can see the loading now.. :) http://www.kongregate.com/games/yossefki/nqueensolver